# How to draw tiles on Map from Database?

Tags: ios, swift3, mapkit, mkoverlay

I am developing a GIS based iOS application using Swift 3.0. I want to draw tiles on Map and tiles images are stored in SQLite Database.

My question is how can I retrieve tile image from database and draw thoses image on Map, as database contains columns zoom (values will be 12, 13, etc.), tile_row (values will be 4122, 3413, etc.), tile_column (values will be 4122, 3413, etc.) and data but I get zoom level value in thousands and I get latitude and longitude values in iOS app, so I need to convert these values to match values in database. I found a way to convert zoom level to 1 to 18 scale but I don't know can I match the tile_row and tile_column value using latitude and longitude.

Also please verify that my code which convert zoom level to 1 to 18 (similar to google map zoom level) is correct:

```
let zoomLevel = Int(log2(360 / MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(mapRect).span.longitudeDelta))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In IOS (and most mapping systems) the tile images are stored in a directory structure where each zoom level is a parent directory named with the zoom-level number.  Under that directory, there are one or more directories named with the longitudinal tile numbers of the tiles below - e.g., at zoom level 10 there are 1024 tiles across and your directories could be 750, 751, 752, and 753 if that's where their images fell relatively.  Under each longitude (x-coordinate) directory are the images (256 X 256 pixels) for that y-coordinate, each named for the x tile coordinate, again out of 1024 at zoom level 10.

To find where you are in those ranges, use  MKMapPointForCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2D), which will give you the lat (y) and lon (x) map points of a location when fully zoomed out.  To get the longitude (y) tile number use:

```
Int((pow(2.0, Double(z)) as Double) * point.y / 268435456.0)
```

...where the big number is the total number of points on the x-axis at zoom level 0 (2^20 tiles * 256 pixels / tile).  That way if point.x is 1/3 of the big number, the image is the tile 1/3 of the way through 1024, and the integer representing the 256-pixel interval (i.e., tile) that number falls into is the name of the directory.

The latitude (y) map point and tile number are calculated similarly, and that number is the name of the image file.  So, at zoom level 10 the image for the tile 752 out of 1024 along the x-axis and 486 out of 1024 along the y-axis would be in the file:

```
...Documents/Maps/yourDirectory/10/752/486.png
```

...provided you name your overall map directory Maps and the specific directory for this set of tiles yourDirectory.  When you use the overlay, you'd use this directory information along with the rest of the setup to instantiate an MKTileOverlay object.  Note that the offsets are from the bottom left corner unless you specify that they're reversed since they're thinking x and y axes (remind you of using CoreGraphics for a UIImage?).

Finally, here's how I calculate the zoom level given two corner points of a region that I want to capture a snapshot for:

```
    let position1 = MKMapPointForCoordinate(bottomRight)
    let position2 = MKMapPointForCoordinate(topLeft)
    let xPosition1 = position1.x / Setting.shared.mapScale
    let xPosition2 = position2.x / Setting.shared.mapScale
    let yPosition1 = position1.y / Setting.shared.mapScale
    let yPosition2 = position2.y / Setting.shared.mapScale

    let relativeSpanX = xPosition1 - xPosition2    // X distance between points relative to size of full map
    let relativeSpanY = yPosition1 - yPosition2    // Y distance between points relative to size of full map
    let spanForZoom = max(relativeSpanX, relativeSpanY)

    startingZoom = max(10, Int(log2(1.0 / spanForZoom)) - 1)
```

That gets you the zoom level for a tile that fits the size of the area that includes both points, but note that no one standard tile of that size (or any size less than the full map) may include those two points depending on where they lie relative to the grid.  For example if they span the prime meridian the first step to 4 tiles at zoom level 1 will separate them, so you may need 2 - 4 tiles of the starting zoom size to get both.  Ideally, write a function that tells you the tile number (x and y) that includes a CLLocationCoordinate2D since that gets very handy as you pick, download, and collect your tiles.

While you can get away with a geometrical approach like you're showing to calculate longitudinal / y-axis values, MKMapPointForCoordinate() is indispensable for latitude / y-axis calculations since the mercator map is non-linear as you move north or south, and the function takes care of that for you.

That should get you started, but it's a picky process - one thing to focus on is the fact that the layout is always from the lower left; it's easy to get confused as you gather and label the tiles.

I use the following function to calculate the x and y coordinates for the tile that a point is in for a given zoom level:

```
func getTileCoordinates(location: CLLocationCoordinate2D, z: Int) -> (x: Int, y: Int)
{
    let point = MKMapPointForCoordinate(location)
    let locationX = Int((pow(2.0, Double(z)) as Double) * point.x / 268435456.0)
    let locationY = Int((pow(2.0, Double(z)) as Double) * point.y / 268435456.0)

    return (locationX, locationY)
}
```

...again, where 268435456.0 is the total number of pixels in the zoom level 20 map along the x or y axis.  Note, all of this is for Apples MapKit maps and the functions to display them.

Comment: BTW, I added the max on the zoom calculation since I didn't want to zoom out any further than level 10 since I'm using the maps to support navigation and you can't afford more than 6 or 7 levels of zoom (at 7 you need over 5,000 tiles!).  The minus 1 is to get a little breathing space and increase the chance that I can get both points onto 1 or 2 tiles.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please explain variables or how to get these variable which you are using like z, point, mapScale. You added code to get zoom level, but I am not sure what is my zoom level, spanForZoom is my zoom level?

Comment: bottomRight and topLeft are at the corners of the area for which I want the map.  I get these by finding the maximum and minimum latitudes and longitudes among the locations in my waypoints and using them to define the two points: bottomRight = (min, max) and topLeft = (max, min).  From there the startingZoom calculation should do the rest to get the zoom.  The .x and .y values in those calculations are properties of the MKMapPoints values returned by the system corresponding to x and y points on a graph.  [see next comment]

Comment: I convert those points to the tile numbers using the first equation that just uses the total number of points in the graph (268435456) and the number of tiles at the zoom level you're using (pow(2.0, Double(z))) to get the numbers of the tile along the x and y axes.  I vary the value of z from the startingZoom to higher values as I pull down and store multiple zoom levels of map tiles into the directory structure. [see next comment]

Comment: For some background on this, I'd recommend the article at http://nshipster.com/mktileoverlay-mkmapsnapshotter-mkdirections/ as well as Apple's documentation for MKTileOverlayPath and MKTileOverlay.  I hope this all helps, I'll admit to spending some time digesting these and other sources and experimenting to get it all to work.

Comment: I am now able to draw only for small portion of top-left corner but then that image is repeatedly drawn on rest of the screen. Can you please tell me what I am missing? FYI I need to draw tiles on Map for central part of New York and only if zoom level is more than 12.

Comment: You said "write a function that tells you the tile number (x and y) that includes a CLLocationCoordinate2D", but I am not able to figure out how to get these tiles number, So can you please explain more about how to get all tiles numbers which fit on the screen?

Comment: OK, it sounds like you're making progress.  I'd download the map files and take a look to see what you're building (in Xcode: Window>Devices to open a window, then in that window select your iPhone then your app in the list and click the gear and download the container. Once it downloads, right click the file and show package contents).  See whether the map images are the same and the issue is the download or they're not and it's the display function.  As to zoom, when you set up the MKTileOverlay object you should be setting its properties for min and max z values.

Comment: See my edits at the end of the answer for the function to return the tile coordinates.

Comment: I am using same method you have given, but only difference is I use mapView.visibleMapRect.origin.x and y. But this will return only one tile number and I am not sure how can I can get more tiles numbers. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By8sjG5yvLlsb3d1cVRQaXh6SVE/view this is what I am getting now, part in yellow box is correct.

Comment: I use it when requesting tile images to get the starting tile, then iterate the x and y values in nested loops (x = 2000, 2001, ... and for each x, y = 1200, 1201, ...)  Then for each tile I request the image based on the lat / lon coordinates of the tile corners and store the tiles in the directory structure.  When I display the tiles as an overlay, I just pass the rectangle and the max / min zoom levels for the overlay.